# Warm the iPhone via code

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Ok, it may sounds stupid but I need the find a piece of code the warms the iPhone quickly and doesn't freeze the whole app.
Does anyone has ever deal with heat and phones?

Comment: You mean like physical temperature up? Why? You are making an app for antarctica people?

Comment: And maybe running a forever while loop on a thread might help you, btw.

Comment: Draining the battery for warming up is a ridiculous idea. A battery is even more efficient if it is not too hot. If the display suffers from low temperatures, just put the device in your pocket.

Comment: This won't get approved for the App Store.

Comment: The app is for an hackhaton and already uses some private APIs, I don't care if it doesn't get approved. Read the comment on the answer below.

Comment: Be a little careful.  I once damaged a Nokia phone (actually melted glue holding the screen together) by leaving it stuck in a loop while on a charger.  (The loop was due to an OS bug related to cast checking.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is weird but I will take a shot at it. Any mishap, like iPhone blowing up etc. if it occurs is not my responsibility. I am assuming you are well aware of what you are doing.

Quickest ways to "warm" your iPhone is to do 2 things (amongst others).

1. Run CPU intensive code (eg. calculate Pi to the nth digit)
2. Start using GPS+Location tracking with 10m accuracy with highest possible location updates.

To run CPU intensive tasks you spawn (say 5) background threads & run infinite some while loops. Also start (5 more) location updates based background threads & subscribe for location updates with the above discussed specs.

Note that any operation which consumes too much battery power is bound to heat up your iPhone. See here for more - [What are the most battery-consuming things you can do in an iPhone-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687883/what-are-the-most-battery-consuming-things-you-can-do-in-an-iphone-app/8687913#8687913)

Do you mind me asking why are you doing this ?

Comment: I'm doing an app for an hackathon, basically the iPhone it will act as an (expensive) heat stone. I was thinking about something CPU intensive but I don't want to stuck the since it's doing networking and playing music among other stuff.

Comment: spawn a background thread & do any such operations there. It should not freeze your UI (since UI runs on main thread).

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off keeping the GPU busy. Constantly animating a huge pile of overlapping transparent views will probably achieve that.

Comment: @SimoneD'Amico what approach(s) did you finally take?

Comment: @SrikarAppal A GCD thread that runs a while loop that check a boolean to know when the phone is hot enough :D I'll put the source on Github, it's a remote massager app: multiple devices heating and vibrating controlled by a leap motion massager.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to run NSRunLoop continuously with very small interval.

```
while(TRUE)
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0001]];
}
```